# How does one use Q.all with chai-as-promised?

Tags: protractor, q, cucumberjs, chai-as-promised

The chai-as-promised docs have the following example of dealing with multiple promises in the same test:

```
it("should all be well", function (done) {
    Q.all([
        promiseA.should.become("happy"),
        promiseB.should.eventually.have.property("fun times"),
        promiseC.should.be.rejectedWith(TypeError, "only joyful types are allowed")
    ]).should.notify(done);
});
```

I assume that the `Q` here has come from `npm install q` and `var Q = require('q');`.

Where does `.should` come from?

When I try this `should` is `undefined` and I get `TypeError: Cannot call method 'notify' of undefined`.

Is there some monkey patching of `Q` that's supposed to happen first? Or am I using the wrong version of something?

I'm using cucumber with protractor. As I understand it they don't support returning promises yet so the user has to handle the call to `done`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

`.should` comes from the "should" assertions style - http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#should. You need to run:

```
chai.should();
```

after `var Q = require('q');` but before `Q.all([]).should.notify...`:

```
var Q = require('q');
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

// ***************
chai.should();
// ***************

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

it("should all be well", function (done) {
    Q.all([
        promiseA.should.become("happy"),
        promiseB.should.eventually.have.property("fun times"),
        promiseC.should.be.rejectedWith(TypeError, "only joyful types are allowed")
    ]).should.notify(done);
});
```

As per the docs:

> This will pass any failures of the individual promise assertions up to the test framework

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly, Q-promise dont have should, i recommend you try this

```
it("should all be well", function (done) {
    Q.all([
        promiseA.should.become("happy"),
        promiseB.should.eventually.have.property("fun times"),
        promiseC.should.be.rejectedWith(TypeError, "only joyful types are allowed")
    ]).then(done);
});
```

also you can use require `mocha-as-promised`, like this:

```
require("mocha-as-promised")();

it("should all be well", function (done) {
    return Q.all([
            promiseA.then(function(someData){
                //here standart chai validation;
            }),
            promiseB.then(function(someData){
                //here standart chai validation;
            });
    ]).then(done);
});
```

Ok, are you add next line to your code?

```
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't pass the test state through to the framework correctly. I've worked out where `should` comes from now; I'll answer my own question I guess...