# Cucumber-Protractor Multiple Expect And Notify

Tags: protractor, cucumber, chai-as-promised

I have a step in my scenario that fills in multiple text fields and selects options from a dropdown.  I want to assert that the text entered and the option selected was correct for each.

```
expect(action1).to.eventually.have.string('some text').and.notify(callback);
expect(action2).to.eventually.have.string('some text').and.notify(callback);
expect(action3).to.eventually.have.string('some text').and.notify(callback);
```

The problem I'm encountering is that the if the first or second expect actions pass then any following actions will not get executed leading to false positives.

Ideally I'm looking for a means to notify without the callback until the last expect.  Anyone know how this might be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found an answer in another StackOverflow question that I did not notice initially.

[How does one use Q.all with chai-as-promised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855210/how-does-one-use-q-all-with-chai-as-promised)

using Q it would look like this:

```
var Q = require('q');
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var should = chai.should();

Q.all([
  expect(action1).to.eventually.have.string('some text'),
  expect(action2).to.eventually.have.string('some text'),
  expect(action3).to.eventually.have.string('some text'),
]).should.notify(callback);
```